# Passing image from different activity and does show with require in an activity

Tags: react-native

This is my code i am run but image does not show after receiving the image source

```
render()
 {const { navigation } = this.props;
 const image = navigation.getParam('image',require('./add1.png'));
 <View style={styles.rightFolderContent}>
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleSliderModal}>
 <Image style={{height:68,width:77}} source={image} />
 </TouchableOpacity>
 </View>
}
```

Comment: Can you put more info about your code

Comment: I am making React Native Application. So, I can select image from an activity and they can pass through navigation from another activity. When class receive the prams they can return image path but they cannot set the Image View where i can display the image.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the Component in the `render` method.
Try this:

```
render()
{
 const { navigation } = this.props;
 const image = navigation.getParam('image',require('./add1.png'));

 return (
   <View style={styles.rightFolderContent}>
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleSliderModal}>
       <Image style={{height:68,width:77}} source={image} />
     </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
 );
}
```

Comment: is `image` a `URL` string or a asset?